# Freeform sync files from their original copies

Tags: macos, freeform

When I copy a file from Finder to Freeform, Freeform creates it's own copy of that file, that is, if I open the original file (that is, using Finder) and edit it somehow, those two files will be different, whereas I would prefer they will be automatically synced in some way. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Have you thought about enabling iCloud syncing for FreeForm?

Comment: No, what's the point? Both files on the same device.

Comment: Maybe one of the files are in iCloud Drive storage?